# Use of "will be" with time clause

Tags: future-tense, time-reference

Can we use future form in below sentence? There is 'after' which indicates time clause (as far as I know present simple or present perfect should be used instead of future in such case) so can I use future tense here ("We will be tired after")?

---

**We will be tired after the training** because we will have been riding a bike for an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. That *after* is not a subordinating conjunction, which would introduce a temporal clause, but a preposition introducing a prepositional phrase.

This prepositional phrase is in the main clause, so there is no rule forbidding a *will* modal.

Contrast *When we have finished training*, which is a temporal clause, and does not allow *will*.